Spring Boot - How configure websocket maximum payload size
I have been trying to configure the maximum payload size for binary and text messages for the Websocket server application in Spring Boot without any success.
It's valid to mention I'm not using AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer for broker messages with STOMP which contains the method to configure the payload size, for example:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registry) {
    registry.setMessageSizeLimit(8 *1024);
    registry.setSendBufferSizeLimit(8 *1024);
    registry.setSendTimeLimit(8 *1024);
  }
}

Also trying to inject ServletServerContainerFactoryBean as part of Websocket configuration bean is not working:
  @Bean
  public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
    ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
      container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(8 * 1024);
      container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(8 * 1024);
      return container;
  }

Using raw websocket handler so far I didn't found the way to configure the limit except inside the AbstractWebSocketHandler instance as part of the method afterConnectionEstablished for every session as follow.
public class WebSocketHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketHandler.class);

    /**
     * @param session
     */
    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) {
        logger.info("Connection established on session: {}", session.getId());

        session.setBinaryMessageSizeLimit(64 * 1024); // Can be loaded from profile configuration parameter
        session.setTextMessageSizeLimit(64 * 1024);   // Can be loaded from profile configuration parameter
    }
}

Question:

Am I missing something, a profile configuration variable, a bean that can be injected, or is this the only way to configure the maximum payload size for websocket messages?

